# remove item from `gcheckcombobox`

Tags: r, gwidgets

I have created a `gcheckcombobox`with the items to be displayes in `printable`:

```
object <- gcheckboxgroup(printable, container=win,use.table=TRUE)
```

and I want to delete the values selected by the user after clicking on a button :

```
addHandlerClicked(obj2,handler = function(h,...){
savable<-svalue(object)

#tried something like this, didn't work
enabled(svalue(object))<<-FALSE

})
```

I tried to "disable" the values I selected but did not work.

Thanks for help

Comment: @jverzani thank you if you can help

Comment: For that I think you need to reset the values displayed (svalues<-)

Comment: @jverzani yes, but the documentation says it should be the same lenght ?

Comment: Umm, number of columns yes. Not rows though. To change columns you would need to create a new widget.